# Is there a macro-free way to do token pasting?

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

I have a lot of repeating code that could be easily reduced using a macro with token pasting. I was wondering if there is anything new in the standard that could provide the same functionality without using a macro. Sample code for reference, just replace `Token` with an actual variable name, and this code repeats over 20 times, with different variables of course.

```
if (Token != PreviousToken)
{
    SomeFunc(SomeEnum::Token,Token);
    PreviousToken = Token;
}
```

Comment: Problem here most likely is the enum token. I personally would pack this stuff into a class, having `token` and `previousToken` as well as the enum value as members. Then you'd call `classInstance.nextToken()` instead of `NEXT_TOKEN(tokenVar)`. Bonus: you then define one variable (class instance) instead of two (token + previous token) for every token type you have.

Comment: @Aconcagua the rest of my code isn't really compatible with these things being bundled up in a class

Comment: Then you might want to provide a [mre] including the incompatible parts. Apart from all that comes to my mind is an appropriately parametrised function.

Comment: How about an array of `{Token, SomeEnum::Token}` and a loop?